# Need to call from jxfs client to jxfs server

Tags: java, rmi

I am very new to jxfs things. I have a requirement to call jxfs server which is in cloud server from the jxfs client which is in ATM environment.. How can i call?.. I need to call this one through the Jxfs RMI concept. It would be appreciated one if any example code is available. If atleast you are having code for calling from jxfs server to jxfs client, please post it.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

One of the interesting things about J/XFS and remote device access (based on RMI) is that it is just matter of configuration.

You need to configure a J/XFS repository in order to handle a remote device (basically set 'remoteAccess' to true).

Then accessing these devices from the programming point of view is just the same as they were local devices.

Architecture is explained here: ftp://ftp.cencenelec.eu/CWA/CEN/WS-J-XFS/cwa14923/cwa14923-01-2004-May.pdf

Details, when programming may differ depending on the J/XFS implementation you are using.

> > Trying to answer your question below:

Whenever you want to access a device remotely in J/XFS,  RMI is used. You need to make the following setup:

- On a server (should be accessible) you need to start a JxfsServer. The JxfsServer will use a Read.repository 
  whith all the ATM's and devices configured on them as workstations, with the right IP addresses.
- On the ATM, you need to install:

  - J/XFS libs
  - J/XFS device services for the devices on the ATM
  - Setup the DSstarter:

    - Will use the SpecificDeviceManagerRMI connecting to the JxfsServer you started before.
- On your server (cloud) wherever you are going to use the J/XFS client you can get the remote controls by performing
  the J/XFS initialization as follows:

  `jxfsDM_ = JxfsDeviceManager.getReference();

  jxfsDM_.initialize("com.jxfs.forum.communication.rmi.SpecificDeviceManagerRMI,<atmWorkstation>,AppTest,2006;<jxfsserverhostname>,");`

Then you can get the remote device controls with `getDevice(...)`, and start using them as if they were local devices.

Please, note that handling RMI ports can be tricky, specially in a secured environment as ATM network. Make sure all the ports you need are open.

Comment: Thanks Jorge!!!. when RMI concept will come here.. If I will configure the Read.repository, DSstartar.cmd and other config files in some other system or server means, Do I need to go with RMI?.. And also I need to know where we will configure Jxfs server and and where we will configure Jxfs Client?.. What are the file are mandatory for Jxfs Server?.. If jxfs client is our side program means(Example : source program in cloud) how can we initialize the device services(Which are available in ATM)?... Please help me..

Comment: I have expanded my answer above.. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Jorge!!!.. In the RMI call, I am able to start the jxfsserver which starts the services(Services are simple java classes and I converted those into the jar file and pasted in the classpath) which are in different system. Now using device manager, I am able to get the services and devices name in some other system.

Comment: But when I am trying to initialize or trying to get the instance of service class using IJxfsBaseControl localIJxfsBaseControl = myDeviceManager.getDevice("CashRecycler"); , Its showing class not found exception. After pasting that jar file with my current system application, its working fine. But the RMI concept is not that one, is it?. Can we get the service classe instance in some other system to access the particular service class?.

Comment: As long as you are using the SpecificDeviceManagerRMI with the right workstation patan you should be able to get all the device services available to retrieve the list of devices. Remote devices are like: deviceName@workstation. I am on holidays now and I don't have the right documentation here. I will give you more details on Monday

Comment: Thanks Jorge... Its very nice to hear you are having the documentatiosn... Kindly provide the related documentations which is more helpful to proceed further...

Comment: Please, can you post your repository file and the result of: myDeviceManager.getDeviceAll(IJxfsConst.JXFS_LEVEL_ALL). Just initialize the JxfsDeviceManager with "com.jxfs.forum.communication.rmi.SpecificDeviceManagerRMI". All info about J/XFS Architectures is here: ftp://ftp.cencenelec.eu/CWA/CEN/WS-J-XFS/cwa14923/cwa14923-01-2004-May.pdf or provided by J/XFS implementator.

Comment: Thanks Jorge... We have achieved JXFS RMI connection.. Now I need some clarifications on this.. I am doing this for ATM device.. whenever I am calling the services (Open, CashIn, CashOut..), it will happend simultaneously.. I need to restrict this services like CashIn service should call after Open service functionality.. I can not get the status of current services.. Every service functionality returns some identification id not status.. If status means i can restrict..how can i get the status.. Kindly help me to sort out this..

Comment: I think you should read J/XFS docs carefully. Just a tip: J/XFS has synchronous and asynchronous commands.  I cannot tell you all about J/XFS in these comments. If you have a specific issue I will be glad to help you anyway but in other question. From my point of view original question has already been answered.